# Although removed 32bit java, Why the error occurs?

Tags: java, r, h2o

I used h2o package before. But it can't do now.
I only have 64-bit java.

[image]

I have java.exe  D:\java\New Foder\java8\bin. Also added path. 
This is error message.

```
> h2o.init()

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
<simpleError in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE): '"D:\java\New Folder\java8;D:\java;\bin\java.exe"' not found>
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
Please download the latest Java SE JDK 8 from the following URL:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="D:\\java\\New Folder\\java8;D:\java;/bin/java.exe": 파일 이름, 디렉터리 이름 또는 볼륨 레이블 구문이 잘못되었습니다
```

I checked regedit. There seems to be no problem. How can it be solved?

Comment: It seems that you set java to be at D:\java\New Folder\java8;D:\java;\bin\java.exe"? But that is not a correct path to java. It should be something like D:\java\New Folder\java8\bin\java.exe" - Just check it inside the windows explorer to have the correct path to the java.exe.

Comment: You May have an old java plugin f

Comment: @Konrad Neitzel Probably not.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDo4k.png

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Then, I'll try reinstall.

Comment: When you set JAVA_HOME, you set it without the bin directory.

Comment: @Konrad Neitzel I have tried based on your answer, but it still is not. It seems like a different problem than setting up a Java pass.

Comment: Reinstall is answer. Thanks. :D

Comment: @Sangwonkim can you post your solution as a response so it's easier for others to see? thanks!

Comment: @Lauren Where to post?

Comment: @Sangwonkim you can use the "post your answer box" directly below where it says "Your Answer". This allows you to answer your own question and get points =).